# Bootstrap: is it possible to change the "has-error" line thickness?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am using the `has-error` class on an input like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta input1="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">


      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 has-error">

        <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control"/>

      </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

But I would like to increase the thickness of the red border, so I tried to add this:

```
<style>

.has-error{

   line-height:3px;
}

</style>
```

But it has no effect, so is it possible to change the thickness of this class and how to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`line-height` is not the property you want to change, try `border-width`. You also need to specify the class to `.form-control`, otherwise your style won't be applied.

```css
.has-error .form-control{
   border-width: 3px;
   border-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta input1="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">


      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 has-error">

        <input type="text" name="input" class="form-control"/>

      </div>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks, do you know how to change the border color also, sorry it was not included in my question

Comment: @Henri I've edited the post. But be cautious when using `!important`. It could make for messy and hard to maintain CSS. There are realy good articles on this matter.

Answer (score -1):

`line-height` has no relevance to border thickness - it sets the vertical size of each line of text inside the element. To set the thickness of a border, use the [`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-width) property:

```
.has-error {
   border-width: 3px;
}
```